# Extracting data from a text file using grep and saving it in another directory

Tags: bash, scripting, grep

I'm trying to extract data from `carslist.txt` and separate it all out into different files using `bash`, `grep` and `sed` when required. I'm currently working with grep and I need to extract data from `carslist.txt` in the main working directory, and then save it in a new file `Vauxhall_Cars.txt` in the `output` directory.

A typical line that I'll be extracting looks like this:

`Vauxhall:Vectra:1999:White:2`

Here's what I have so far:

```
#CS101 Assignment BASH script

CARFILE=$1
while [ ! -f "$CARFILE" ]
do
echo "We cannot detect a car file to load, please enter the new filename and press [ENTER]"
read CARFILE
done
echo "We have detected that you're using $CARFILE as your cars file, please continue."

if [ -f output ]
then
echo "Sorry, a file called 'output' exists in the working directory. The script will now exist."
elif [ -d output ]
then
echo "The directory 'output' has been detected, instead of creating a new one we'll be working in there instead."
else
mkdir output
echo "We couldn't find an existing file or directory named 'output' so we've made one for you. Aren't we generous?"
fi
#change working directory to output so it's easier to save the extracted information
cd output
echo "*** Detecting cars with Vauxhall***"
grep -n 'Vauxhall' $CARFILE > Vauxhall_Cars.txt
echo "We've saved all Vauxhall information in the 'Vauxhall_Cars.txt' file. The script will now continue."
```

**With the problem happening here:**

```
cd output
echo "*** Detecting cars with Vauxhall***"
grep -n 'Vauxhall' $CARFILE > Vauxhall_Cars.txt
echo "We've saved all Vauxhall information in the 'Vauxhall_Cars.txt' file. The script will now continue."
```

If I don't change the directory to output, the script runs fine and saves the data from `carslist.txt` to the main working directory, but I need it to be saved in the `output` directory.

How can I achieve this?

Another question that I've just come across. When the lines are taken from `carslist.txt` and put into `Vauxhall_Cars.txt`, they're saved with their line reference like so:

`2:Vauxhall:Vectra:1999:White:2`

With the initial `2:` giving the line reference. Any idea how I can take this out automatically?

Thanks in advance everyone.

Comment: Show your desired output for that sample input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I don't change the directory to output, the script runs fine and saves the data from carslist.txt to the main working directory, but I need it to be saved in the output directory.
>
> How can I achieve this?

Simply redirect to a file in the output directory:

```
grep -n 'Vauxhall' $CARFILE > output/Vauxhall_Cars.txt
```

> Another question that I've just come across. When the lines are taken
>   from carslist.txt and put into Vauxhall_Cars.txt, they're saved with
>   their line reference like so:
>
> 2:Vauxhall:Vectra:1999:White:2
>
> With the initial 2: giving the line reference. Any idea how I can take
>   this out automatically?

Yeah, it's actually not the line number, but the count of hits. This is because you are using `grep -n`. Take away the `-n` flag and it's fixed:

```
grep 'Vauxhall' $CARFILE > output/Vauxhall_Cars.txt
```

Comment: That is absolutely perfect, thanks a lot buddy. I'll mark this as accepted as soon as i can.